# D3js line chart not transitioning, Tooltip error on new bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having trouble with a bar & lines chart which I am setting up to transition data. See [JSFiddle here for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/E4av2/). I am a week old to JSFiddle & D3js so any help is appreciated!

The issues are:

1. Green line is not transitioning
2. Any new bars added to the chart after the "update" do not show tooltip. Inspect shows a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of null in d3.tip.min.js which is the cause of this.

I am calling the chart to create and update via buttons. Once created and updated the fiddle has to be re-started for it to work again.

Code here:

```
<input id="clickMe1" type="button" value="Create Chart" onclick='createMainPerfChart()' />
<input id="clickMe2" type="button" value="Update Chart" onclick='updateMainPerfChart()' />
<div style="margin-top:120px;">
    <svg id="mainchart"></svg>
</div>
```

PS: Lars, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got just a few minor things in there, in particular

1. The problem here is a simple typo. You need to do `svg.selectAll("path.TGTLine")` and not `svg.selectAll("path.TargetAvg")`.
2. It looks like d3.tip doesn't like to have two tooltips with the same class. You can solve this by simply reusing the definition of `tip` instead of declaring it twice.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E4av2/35/).